# JavaScript if statement doesn't seem to be comparing string for certain values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a simple discord bot for fun and decided to make it read a text file and only display lines that start with the strings I set. I am using the node module n-readlines and the following code that I've written worked initially.

```
function readLatestCrashReport() {
    const lineByLine = require('n-readlines');
    const liner = new lineByLine('tests/crash-report.txt');
    let line, linesToPrint = 0, stackTraceFound = false, errors = [];

    while (line = liner.next()) {
        line = line.toString('ascii').toLowerCase();

        if (line.substring(0, 12) === 'description:') {
            errors.push(line);

        } else if (line === 'stacktrace:') {
            errors.push(line);
            linesToPrint = 3;
            stackTraceFound = true;

        } else if (linesToPrint > 0 && line !== '') {
            linesToPrint--;
            errors.push(line);

        } else if (stackTraceFound === true && linesToPrint < 1) {
            liner.close();

        }
    }

    if (errors.length !== 0) {
        return errors.join('\n');

    } else {
        return 'No Description Or Stacktrace Could Be Found';

    }
}
```

and it was reading from the a crash-report.txt file that contained:

```
Description: Initializing

Stacktrace:
    Printed first line
    Printed second line
    Printed third line
    Not printed fourth line
    Not printed fifth line

    Not printed seventh line
```

The outcome, initially, was:

```
Description: Initializing
Stacktrace:
    Printed first line
    Printed second line
    Printed third line
```

which is perfect, but I come back the next day and all that outputs this time is:

```
Description: Initializing
```

I thought that was strange so I console.logged `line` to see what was happening and the console was as expected:

```
Description: Initializing

Stacktrace:
    Printed first line
    Printed second line
    Printed third line
    Not printed fourth line
    Not printed fifth line

    Not printed seventh line
```

For some reason the if statement seems to work for the first line and then proceeds to not work for any of the other if statements.
I've tried changing the `===` to just `==` but that didn't change anything. I added more `Description: Initializing` lines and it just prints them all but completely ignores `Stacktrace:` and I finally tried switching the if statements around and it still only prints `Description: Initializing`. Am I doing something wrong or is JavaScript somehow messing up?

Comment: Are you sure there is no space after the "Stacktrace:" in the input file? Maybe adding a .trim() after toLowerCase() would help?

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have worked but it's weird how it only just started doing this now. This originally worked on MAC but seemed to break on Windows unless you add trim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using .trim(), the reason it works on MAC and not Windows could be down to how they handle new lines. Mac just uses `'\n'` while Windows uses `'\r\n'`.